# How to add modernizr build so that I can properly check Modernizr.capture? (currently always undefined)

Tags: input, camera, modernizr

I need to check if the user's device can input from a camera on my site. To do this I am attempting to use modernizr. I have followed the steps/example code provided on their site but when I test the `capture` attribute, I always get undefined, regardless of if I am on a device that supports `capture`.

Steps I followed:

1. [I browsed for the input[capture] attribute and added it to the build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9aTf.png)
2. [I copied the demo code to check this feature and added it to my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVURI.png)
3. [I downloaded the build, added the js file to my project, and included the appropriate reference in my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mb51w.png)

However after all of this, when inspecting `Modernizr.capture` in the chrome inspector, [it always shows up as undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJBKs.png).

My basic check function is as follows:

```
    $scope.hasCamera = function() {
        if (Modernizr.capture) {
            // supported
            return true;
        } else {
            // not-supported
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This is my first time using Modernizr. Am I missing a step or doing something incorrectly? I also installed modernizr using npm install and tried adding the reference to a json config file from the command line.

Alternatively, how might I check if my device has a camera?

Thank you very much for your time. Please let me know if I am being unclear or if you need any additional information from me.

Answer (score 0):

A few things

1. while photos are helpful, actual code hosted in a public website (either your own project, or on something like jsbin.com) is 10x as useful. As a result, I am not sure why it is coming back as undefined.
2. The actual capture detect [is quite simple](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/blob/97b6a4e05b95b7e6722c83c5a5adbd423100ad45/feature-detects/forms/capture.js). It all comes down to this

var capture = 'capture' in document.createElement('input')`

3. Your code is a lot more complicated than it needs to be. Lets break it down. You trying to set `$scope.hasCamera` to equal the result of `Modernizr.capture`, and you are using a function to check the value of `Modernizr.capture`, and if it is true, return `true`. If it is false, return `false`. There is a fair bit of duplicated logic, so we can break it down from the inside out.

Firstly, your testing for a true/false value, and then returning the same value. That means you could simplify the code by just returning the value of `Modernizr.capture`

```
$scope.hasCamera = function() {
  return Modernizr.capture
}
```

While Modernizr will always be giving you a boolean value (when it is functioning - without seeing your actual code I can't say why it is coming back as undefined), if you are unsure of the value you can add `!!` before it to coerce it into a boolean. In your case, it would make `undefined` into `false`

```
$scope.hasCamera = function() {
  return !!Modernizr.capture
}
```

At this point, you can see that we are setting up a function just to return a static value. That means we can just set assign that static value directly to the variable rather than setting up a function to do that

```
$scope.hasCamera = !!Modernizr.capture
```

Now, the final thing you may be able to do something better is if you are only using Modernizr for this one feature. Since it is such a simple feature detection, it is overkill to be using all of Modernizr.

$scope.hasCamera = 'capture' in document.createElement('input')`